# Is the math jobs wiki around this year (2013)?

Tags: job-search, career-path, mathematics

For the past few years there has been a [math jobs wiki](http://notable.math.ucdavis.edu/wiki/Mathematics_Jobs_Wiki) with lists of posted jobs together with "rumors" about shortlists, interviews and offers. This year the website hasn't been working. Does anyone know if the website will be available this year?

Comment: can somebody edit the mathjobs wiki page???

Answer (score 8):

Here's [the reply from Greg Kuperberg](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/952/where-are-mathematics-jobs-advertised-if-not-on-mathjobs-e-g-in-europe-and-els#comment368742_3753) to this exact question asked a month ago on MathOverflow.

> I will put it back up soon. –  Greg Kuperberg, Sep 24 at 10:56

It'll be up soon unless he has changed his mind. Upvoting the comment there might help... hopefully.

Comment: **It is now up and running!**